# Why I can't access a function inside a class, using PHP

Tags: php, function, class

An Error occurred when a function is called inside a Class.

The error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$arquivo' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sequencial\function_sintegra.php on line 20
```

Here I provide my code:

```
<?php

function explode_txt(){

    $arquivo = $_SESSION['nomeArquivo'];
    $conteudo = file_get_contents($arquivo);
    $linhas = explode("\n", $conteudo);
}

class Sintegra{

    private $emissor;
    private $cnpj;
    private $inscricao;
    private $municipio;
    private $estado;
    private $dataInicial;
    private $dataFinal;

    $arquivo = explode_txt(); //Arquivo Sintegra em array nesta variavel, por linhas.

    $emissor = (string)substr($arquivo[0], 30, 35);
    $inscricao = (string)substr($arquivo[0], 16, 14);
    $cnpj = (string)substr($arquivo[0], 2, 14);

}

?>
```

Is there something wrong with how I access the function?
I have tried to browse but could not find any solution. 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call outside function in class method.

You can do this way:

```
class Sintegra{

    private $emissor;
    private $cnpj;
    private $inscricao;
    private $municipio;
    private $estado;
    private $dataInicial;
    private $dataFinal;

    public function __construct() {
        $arquivo = explode_txt();

        $this->emissor = (string)substr($arquivo[0], 30, 35);
        $this->inscricao = (string)substr($arquivo[0], 16, 14);
        $this->cnpj = (string)substr($arquivo[0], 2, 14);
    }
}
```

**Update**
This is the best way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But now i can't use this variables outsite the construct. :/

Comment: Are you talking about `$arquivo`?

Comment: Yes, the `$arquivo` outsite/inside the class don't show the inputs.

Comment: Then you can have `$arquivo` as a class property and access it in constructor using `$this->`. Example: `$this->arquivo = explode_txt();
 $this->emissor = (string)substr($this->arquivo[0], 30, 35);
 $this->inscricao = (string)substr($this->arquivo[0], 16, 14);
 $this->cnpj = (string)substr($this->arquivo[0], 2, 14);`

Comment: Don't forget to add `public $arquivo;` after `private $dataFinal;` if you follow my above comment.

Comment: Exactly, i will post the full code in another answer to a better view.